# How do I build and run the code from github for NS3 in the link provided

Tags: ns-3, mptcp

How do I build and run the code from github for NS3 in the link provided below 
https://github.com/mkheirkhah/mptcp

Answer (score 0):

it has already ns3 installation steps  with mptcp
**https://github.com/mkheirkhah/mptcp**
this is the Installations steps go according to it ul get to know

We have tested this code on Mac (with llvm-gcc42 and python 2.7.3-11) and several Linux distributions (e.g. Red Hat with gcc4.4.7 or Ubuntu16.4 with gcc5.4.0).

Clone the MPTCP's repository
git clone https://github.com/mkheirkhah/mptcp.git
Configure and build
CXXFLAGS="-Wall" ./waf configure build 
Run a simulation
./waf --run "mptcp"

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Kashif-Nadeem/ns-3-dev-git is the more recent fork of https://github.com/teto/ns-3-dev-git/wiki which started as mkheirkhah's fork.
It should work with the latest ns-3. Compared to mkheirkhah's approach (I haven't checked if it is still valid), it tries to reuse the TCP socket code so that it can use TCP socket application. You can read more details from https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313623789_An_Implementation_of_Multipath_TCP_in_ns3